# ERROR Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "hds-icon" has already been used with this registry

Tags: reactjs, webpack, micro-frontend

`I am trying to create a React Micro frontend

**App 1 **

webpack.config.js :

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const  webpack  = require("webpack");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;
const devDeps = require('./package.json').devDependencies;

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".css", ".scss", ".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              url: {
                filter: (url) => {
                  if (url.startsWith("data:")) {
                    return false;
                  }
                  return true;
                },
              },
            },
          },
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: ["babel-loader"],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
  
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "public", "index.html"),
    }),
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "FIRST_APP",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        "./app": "./src/components/App",
      },
       
     
    }),
  ],
 
};
```

**hds-react-components is just a webcomponent in Package.json**

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "micro-host",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack serve --watch-files ./src"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-select": "^5.7.7",
    "@here/hds-grid": "2023.10.5",
    "@here/hds-react-components": "2023.10.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "sass": "^1.58.3",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  }
}
```

App 2 (Parent )

webpack.config.js:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    uniqueName: 'my-package-xyz',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".css", ".scss", ".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              url: {
                filter: (url) => {
                  if (url.startsWith("data:")) {
                    return false;
                  }
                  return true;
                },
              },
            },
          },
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: ["babel-loader"],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "public", "index.html"),
    }),
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "MICRO",
      remotes: {
        FIRST_APP: 'FIRST_APP@http://localhost:8080/remoteEntry.js',
      },
      shared: {
        ...deps,
        react: { singleton: true, eager: true, requiredVersion: deps.react },
        "react-dom": {
          singleton: true,
          eager: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
        },
        "@here/hds-react-components": {
          singleton: true,
          eager: true,
          requiredVersion: "2023.10.5",
        },
        "@here/hds-grid": {
          singleton: true,
          eager: true,
          requiredVersion: "2023.10.5",
        },
        "react-select": {
          singleton: true,
          eager: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["react-select"],
        },
        "@here/hds-icon": {
          singleton: true,
          eager: true,
          requiredVersion: "2023.10.5",
        },
      },
    }),
  ]
};
```

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "micro-host",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack serve --watch-files ./src"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@here/hds-grid": "2023.10.5",
    "@here/hds-react-components": "2023.10.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-select": "^5.7.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "sass": "^1.58.3",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import('./bootstrap');
```

bootstrap.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("container");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
 
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

`react.development.js:1408 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "hds-icon" has already been used with this registry
at eval (webpack://micro-host/./node_modules/@here/hds-base/build/utils.js?:111:35)
at __decorate (webpack://micro-host/./node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.mjs?:93:93)
at eval (webpack://micro-host/./node_modules/@here/hds-icon/build/hds-icon.js?:215:66)
at ./node_modules/@here/hds-icon/build/hds-icon.js (http://localhost:8080/vendors-node_modules_here_hds-base_build_hds-styles_css-node_modules_here_hds-grid_build_hds--8f30e8.js:1998:1)
at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:8080/remoteEntry.js:330:33)
at fn (http://localhost:8080/remoteEntry.js:564:21)
at eval (webpack://micro-host/./node_modules/@here/hds-icon/build/index.js?:5:70)
at ./node_modules/@here/hds-icon/build/index.js (http://localhost:8080/vendors-node_modules_here_hds-base_build_hds-styles_css-node_modules_here_hds-grid_build_hds--8f30e8.js:2008:1)
at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:8080/remoteEntry.js:330:33)
at fn (http://localhost:8080/remoteEntry.js:564:21)``